# display friends list in android application using XMPP

Tags: android

I am working on a chat application. I need to display friends list in android application using XMPP. can someone guide me how to do that. Any sample example will be of great use to me.

i have developed the below code.

```
 public void friendslist()
    {
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

    System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
    for(RosterEntry r:entries)
    {
    System.out.println(r.getUser());
    }
    }
```

I need to display all my contacts in a list view. how can i achive it. I shall be happy if i could get the answer that could solve my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/), that works on Android (Ignite Realtime developed Openfire). It's generally the most commonly used Android XMPP library as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I need someone to tell me how to display my friends list in LISTVIEW. I need to get data from xmpp and display them ina listview.. Any sample code

Comment: @Coder the person is alreay using the library that u have suggested him. OK

Comment: @Coder_sLaY .. Am in the same situation am  able to print it ..but cant able to add them to hashmap please help ..

Comment: @Coder_sLaY I have enough knowledge regarding the XMPP to help you, please post a separate query and give me the link, I will help you for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are suppose to create a model class with name BuddyInfo, with fields like name, first_name, last_name, jid, email, etc.

```
public List<BuddyInfo> getFriendList() {

    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
    mContactList = new ArrayList<BuddyInfo>();
    BuddyInfo buddyInfo = null;

    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

            String buddy = entry.getUser();
            buddyInfo = new BuddyInfo();
            System.out.println(entry.getUser().trim());         

            VCard vCard = new VCard();

        try {
            vCard.load(mConnection, buddy);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String buddyName = vCard.getFirstName();    

        buddyInfo.setUserName(buddyName);
        .
        .
        .
        .
        // like that you can access all the fields that you require from vcard object.

        mContactList.add(buddyInfo);
    }

       return mContactList;
}
```

Now you have list of buddies from your roster, so you have to implement it with your custom list adapter. That's it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

used AsynTask to get Roster list below code is working fine for me.

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(xmpptcpConnection);
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            Log.d("Roster","buddy size :: " + entries.size());
            for(RosterEntry rosterEntry : entries){
                Log.d("Roster","Name is : " + rosterEntry);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }.execute((Void[]) null);
```

Comment: please edit your answer, add some context and why you write this code. Code only answer are considered low quality and subject to be deleted.